# How to do a conditional import in gradle based on package id?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to do a conditional import in the gradle based on the package id. Because I manage these package ids according to the hardware on which I will generate the app. I do this due to the specificity of each platform (Pax, Getnet, etc.).

However, in one of the imported dependencies, it causes an error due to simply importing it into another platform (smartphones). I would like to know if anyone can help me how do I import a dependency conditionally if it is the specific platform?

```
if (myPackageId == 'com.paxmyApp.myApp')
     implementation 'com.paxDependencies: x.x.x'
```